# NSIS: Silently fails with RequestExecutionLevel user

Tags: nsis

I am less than experienced in Windows applications and even more, this is my first effort to create an installer so I am just reading around about UAC without being able to understand what is happening!

Anyway, I am trying to create an installer with RequestExecutionLevel user and it seems, whatever I tried, the installer silently fails on my Windows 10 machine... That means nothing is copied to the install folder although it seems that the installer finishes successfully and even worse, I can't find any local logs or problematic entries in the windows event logs...

This is my nsis script:

```
############################################################################################
#      NSIS Installation Script created by NSIS Quick Setup Script Generator v1.09.18
#               Entirely Edited with NullSoft Scriptable Installation System                
#              by Vlasis K. Barkas aka Red Wine red_wine@freemail.gr Sep 2006               
############################################################################################

!define APP_NAME "..."
!define COMP_NAME "..."
!define WEB_SITE "..."
!define VERSION "00.00.00.00"
!define COPYRIGHT "..."
!define DESCRIPTION "Application"
!define INSTALLER_NAME "D:\PATH_TO\Installer.exe"
!define MAIN_APP_EXE "AppName.exe"
!define INSTALL_TYPE "SetShellVarContext current"
!define REG_ROOT "HKCU"
!define REG_APP_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!define UNINSTALL_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APP_NAME}"

######################################################################

VIProductVersion  "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey "ProductName"  "${APP_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey "CompanyName"  "${COMP_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright"  "${COPYRIGHT}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription"  "${DESCRIPTION}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion"  "${VERSION}"

######################################################################

SetCompressor ZLIB
Name "${APP_NAME}"
Caption "${APP_NAME}"
OutFile "${INSTALLER_NAME}"
BrandingText "${APP_NAME}"
XPStyle on
InstallDirRegKey "${REG_ROOT}" "${REG_APP_PATH}" ""
InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\ProductName\"
RequestExecutionLevel user

######################################################################

!include "MUI.nsh"

!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_UNABORTWARNING

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!ifdef LICENSE_TXT
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${LICENSE_TXT}"
!endif

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_NODISABLE
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_DEFAULTFOLDER "AppName"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_ROOT "${REG_ROOT}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_KEY "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "${REG_START_MENU}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $SM_Folder
!endif

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

######################################################################

Section -MainProgram
${INSTALL_TYPE}
SetOverwrite ifnewer
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "${FILES_PATH}test.txt"
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section -Icons_Reg
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_BEGIN Application
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${WEB_SITE}"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_END
!endif

!ifndef REG_START_MENU
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\AppName"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\AppName\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${WEB_SITE}"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\AppName\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif
!endif

WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${REG_APP_PATH}" "" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayName" "${APP_NAME}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayVersion" "${VERSION}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "Publisher" "${COMP_NAME}"

!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "URLInfoAbout" "${WEB_SITE}"
!endif
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section Uninstall
${INSTALL_TYPE}
Delete "$INSTDIR\test.txt"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif

RmDir "$INSTDIR"

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_GETFOLDER "Application" $SM_Folder
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME}.lnk"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk"
!endif
Delete "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk"

RmDir "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder"
!endif

!ifndef REG_START_MENU
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\AppName\${APP_NAME}.lnk"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\AppName\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk"
!endif
Delete "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk"

RmDir "$SMPROGRAMS\AppName"
!endif

DeleteRegKey ${REG_ROOT} "${REG_APP_PATH}"
DeleteRegKey ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
SectionEnd

######################################################################
```

Do you spot anything strange? Seems like a permissions problem, but do you know how to debug this?

Thanks!

### EDIT

As requested, I provided the entire script!

Comment: This is not a complete installer script, it does not install anything, there are no sections and no pages! Please post a minimal example I can actually compile.

Comment: Thanks Anders, I posted the entire script

Comment: This new example has "RequestExecutionLevel user" commented out!

Comment: yes, because it is not working. I am, of course trying without the comment.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

NSIS should display a retry/ignore/abort dialog if it is unable to extract a file.

After I made these changes:

```
!define FILES_PATH ".\"
!appendfile ".\test.txt" "Hello World$\r$\n"
...
!define APP_NAME "NsisTest"
!define MAIN_APP_EXE "NsisTest.exe"
```

then your code works just fine for me, both on Windows 8 and the latest Windows 10.

You have `WriteUninstaller` in your icons section which is a bit strange and you forgot `Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"` in your uninstall section but these issues should not prevent it from writing anything.

Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see where/if it extracts your files. Did you look in "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\**ProductName**?